# Proving by contradiction

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, parity

> Consider the statement:  For all $x, y, z ∈ Z$.  At least one of
> $x−y$, $x−z$ and $y−z$ is even. Prove this statement by contradiction.

So the contradictory statement would be that neither one of $x−y$, $x−z$ and $y−z$ is even, eg they're all odd. I know how to do the proof, but with proof by contradiction, would I be allowed to let $x$,$y$, and $z$ equal actual integers, eg $1,2,3$ or would I have to make them equal eg. $2k+3$, $2m+6$ and $2n+8$ to complete this proof?

Comment: No.  Going through examples might be useful, but you can't prove the claim that way.  After all, taking $x=y=z$ we 'd have examples in which all three differences were even, but that would not be generally true.

Comment: If $x-y, y-z, $ and $z-x$ were three odd numbers, then their sum $(0)$ would be odd -- a contradiction

Answer (score 1):

By the way of contradictio, assume that $x-y$, $z-x$ and $y-z$ are odd numbers.

By adding all three, you get: $(x-y)+(z-x)+(y-z)=0$. But the sum of three odd numbers must be odd. And here you have a contradiction.

MOREOOVER. This proof says that it is also impossible to have exactly 1 odd numbers among them.

Comment: You mean to assume that they are all odd, and the sum of 3 odds must be odd, correct?

Comment: Replace "even" by "odd".

Comment: AW YESSSSS, sorry. Yet edited.

Comment: Also, it is possible to have $2$ odd number and $1$ even, as odd + odd + even = even

Comment: @kafo being odd or even is independent of the sign: $\alpha\in\Bbb Z$ is odd $\iff$ $-\alpha$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Assume WLOG that $x-y$ and $y-z$ are both odd (if at least one is even, we are done). However, this means that $(x - y) + (y - z) = x - z$ is even. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the question "Would I be able to let $x,y,z$ equal actual integers?":

No. One example of the converse being right is sufficient to disprove a claim, however one example of the converse being wrong is not sufficient to prove it.

You must assume that $x-z, y-z, x-y$ are *arbitrary* odd numbers, and find a way to show that this makes no sense.

Comment: thank you. Would the contradiction to the original statement be that "neither one of x−y, x−z and y−z is even" or would it be "neither one of x−y, x−z and y−z is odd"?

Comment: Neither. You assume "they are all odd", so the contradiction is simply "they are not all odd" (i.e. at least one must be even)

Comment: But isn't that the same as the original statement (at least one is even) which you have to find a contradiction for?

Comment: Ah my bad, I misunderstood your question. If the original statement  is "at least one of them is even" the contradiction is "none of them are even", i.e. all are odd. Works both ways

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach : pigeonhole principle.

Given integers, $a,b$ then $2 | (a-b) \iff a,b$ have the same parity (odd or even).

There are only two parities : odd or even.  Given three #'s, $x,y,z$ then two of them must have the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and suppose all of $x-y, x-z,y-z$ were all not even. Then they must all be odd. We know that an odd integer plus or minus an odd integer returns an even integer, so we will check some cases.

$(x-y)-(x-z)=x-y-x+z=z-y$ which is even. However, because we know $-(y-z)=z-y$, then we have that an even integer is equal to an odd integer, a contradiction.

You can check through the other possible cases to show that none of the configurations will hold.